# Cross-server javascript issue? js on one server, accessing another server

Tags: javascript, flex3

I had a question. I have a coldfusion server that has javascript, and I am using Flex on another server. I need to use javascript from the CF server to access the Flex server, and wanted to know if there would be any cross-server (same domain though) issues that would arise. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CORS instead of Ajax, part of HTML 5. Ajax doesn't allow Cross Site Scripting. But the CORS allows. They are all the same, but you should set some additional headers when request, and server should check the headers and response them. take a look at this [page.](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) and also [this one](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/)

Answer (score 0):

There won't be any issues.

JavaScript does't care what language you use to serve up your pages and/or data. The only thing it cares about is 1) is it valid and 2) is it from the same domain as the requesting page.

Nothing else matters.